Unsatisfied Dependency Exception: Error creating bean with name & Also getting Invalid client token
{Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'leadCreationServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\AAA\IdeaProjects\lead-management-integration-lead-creation\build\classes\java\main\com\abc\leadmanagement\lead_creation\service\impl\LeadCreationServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.abc.leadmanagement.aws_configs.service.impl.AmazonSQSServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessagingTemplate' defined in com.abc.leadmanagement.aws_configs.configs.AmazonSQSConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider' defined in com.abc.leadmanagement.aws_configs.configs.AmazonSQSConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider]: Factory method 'stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: e34930f45-b36d-48ff-8bc9-f364e29a8f18; Proxy: null)
